# Repeated @ExtendWith in Kotlin & JUnit 5

Tags: junit, kotlin, junit5

I'm using JUnit 5 in a Kotlin project and observing behavior that does not match the documentation.
When using multiple `@ExtendWith` annotations on a test class I receive the following error:

`Repeatable annotations with non-SOURCE retention are not yet supported`

[image]

In the [`Extension` section of the JUnit documentation](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions-registration-declarative) this is listed as a valid option.
I'm using Kotlin 1.3.10 and JUnit 5.3.2

Why am I unable to repeat the `@ExtendWith` annotation on my test classes?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Repeatable annotations are [not yet supported in Kotlin](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-12794). You can, however, use the [Extensions](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.3/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/extension/Extensions.html) annotation:

```
@Extensions(
    ExtendWith(...),
    ExtendWith(...)
)
```

Comment: This solution is not working for Kotlin `1.3.50` and JUnit5 `5.5.1` within a local Android unit test.

Answer (score 5):

You can put all classes inside a single annotation:

```
@ExtendWith(
    A::class,
    B::class
)
```